# Link to an anchor (headline id) inside a SourceForge wiki page

Tags: sourceforge

I develop an open source application under the [SourceForge web](https://sourceforge.net). I would like to be able to link to anchors (headline ids) inside a wiki page. The [Markdown Syntax Guide](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/markdown_syntax/) does not mention how to do that. I looked at the HTML code of one of my existing wiki pages and there are no ids assigned to headlines by default.

I suppose there might be a way to do what I want as this seems to be an important feature. Besides, the Markdown Syntax Guide itself has ids assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard HTML to insert an anchor to the text:

```
<span id="myHeading">My heading</span>
======================================
```

and then link to it like this:

```
[My heading](./#myHeading)
```